# Make SignalR's JavaScript library work with JQuery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr, jquery-3

JQuery is up to version 3.1.  In version 3 it seems they removed the methods `.load`, `.unload` and `.error`.

But SignalR's JavaScript library still seems to use those.

**Is there a way to work around this so I don't have to use an older version of JQuery?** (or try to have more than on in my web app).

I am hoping that there is some fancy command I can run that will shim the missing methods....

Comment: Suggest you use migrate plugin to inventory all the issues. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SignalR, Javascript and JQuery 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363605/signalr-javascript-and-jquery-3)

Comment: @charlietfl - Does it just inventory issues?  Or does it provide workarounds too? (I can't quite tell from the page.)

Comment: I don't think it provides workarounds. Likely more details on jQ site

Comment: This is going to be fixed in 2.2.1 that is shipping soon. As a workaround you can change you jquery.signalr.js as follows: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/1feff64b48f611030cfad8827488dbdf6ea91177

Answer (score 0):

Just replace e.load wiht $ in jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js

Then 100 % good luck

Easy Dude